# Android - READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission not working until restart

Tags: android, thumbnails, android-permissions, permission-denied, mediastore

Making a gallery app I query images for a specific folder using a MediaStore cursor query.

Following the new permission API for Lolipop and above versions when I need to access the device memory I check if the permission is available and if not I ask for it. After the permission is granted I restart the activity and the cursor successfuly brings the image entries (which indicates that the permission is trully granted).

But later in the code flow I try to retrieve the bitmaps for those entries and I get a permission error using this:

```
Bitmap bm=MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail( context.getContentResolver(), imageId, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
```

LogCat says:

```
E/ThumbnailUtils(22666): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Music/New Folder 2/subfolder/img.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

If I force close the app and restart it using System.exit(0) everything works ok and bitmaps are successfuly retrieved. I don't understand what is going on...Is this a bug in the OS? Any help???

My permission logic:

```
String permission = Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,  permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;){
     getImagesFromFolder(folderPath);
}
else{
    if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(athis, permission)){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode); 
    }
    else{
        showPermissionProblemDialog();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch(requestCode){
    case REQUEST_READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION:
        finish();
        if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            startActivity(getIntent().addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION));
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0); 
        }
        else{
            F.toastLong(con, "ImageGallery cannot open without the read external storage permission");
        }
        break;
    }
}


public void getImagesFromFolder(String folderPath){
    String sortBy=MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED+" desc";
    String selection=MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA +" like?";    
    String[] selectionArgs=new String[]{"%"+folderPath+"%"};
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED,MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query( uri, projection,  selection, selectionArgs, sortBy); 
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: show your permission model?

Comment: I updated the quesiton to include permission logic. But I don't see how that affects anything. That part works ok. I do get the permission...The problem is that the Thumbnails class doesn't "know" that I have the permission until the app restarts

Answer (score 0):

Try this permission model on the button click where you access gallery.

```
       if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Signup.this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: Denied");
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Signup.this,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: Requesting with explanation?");
                    Snackbar.make(v, "Allow accessing your gallery.", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                            .setAction("GRANT", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Signup.this,
                                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                            1);
                                }
                            })
                            .show();

                } else {
                    Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: Requesting implicitly");
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Signup.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            1);
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: Granted");
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
```

Make sure to override `onPermissionRequestResult`

```
 @Override
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: Granted");
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot access gallery. Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```